# NamedCredential soap request authentication headers

Tags: soap, xml, namedcredentials

I have a WSDL file which can't be imported in Salesforce, so I am currently using the Dom.Document to write my own soap envelope to connect to a webservice.

In my soap envelope I have to set credentials in the soap header:

```
<soapenv:Header>
  <soap:HeaderLogin>
     <soap:username>?</soap:username>
     <soap:password>?</soap:password>
  </soap:HeaderLogin>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Preferably I would like to use a NamedCredential to setup authentication for this webservice. But how can I pass this information from the NamedCredential to the soap header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Named Credential configuration, make sure you specify "Allow Merge Fields in HTTP Body", which will allow you to use the merge fields from your Named Credential. Then, use the $Credential global variables to specify that you want to use the username and password from the Named Credential:

```
<soapenv:Header>
  <soap:HeaderLogin>
     <soap:username>{!$Credential.UserName}</soap:username>
     <soap:password>{!$Credential.Password}</soap:password>
  </soap:HeaderLogin>
</soapenv:Header>
```

You may also need to specify HTMLENCODE for special characters:

```
<soapenv:Header>
  <soap:HeaderLogin>
     <soap:username>{!HTMLENCODE($Credential.UserName)}</soap:username>
     <soap:password>{!HTMLENCODE($Credential.Password)}</soap:password>
  </soap:HeaderLogin>
</soapenv:Header>
```

You can read more about this feature in [Merge Fields for Apex Callouts That Use Named Credentials](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials_merge_fields.htm).

Comment: Additional info: This also works in apex when settings the callout as endpoint in you http request and settings '{!$Credential.Password}' somewhere in the dom: node.addChildElement('username', ns, null).addTextNode('{!$Credential.UserName}');